# to read particular lines from a file after Pattern is found

Tags: sed

I am quite new to shell programing, so please bear with my ignorance,i want to write a sh script in which i want to do following things

1).Find a pattern in the file < Done >

2).After pattern is found read all the lines ,immediately following pattern, that starts with "at". .

excerpt from my log file

```
SQLError.dispatchException(SQLError.java:299)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
```

here i am able to find pattern `SQLError.dispatchException` but dont know how to read all the lines that are starting with `at` and check if `Caused by` is coming immediately after line begins with `at`.

Comment: So what's the expected output?

Comment: What have you written / tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '/SQLError.dispatchException/ {f=1} f && /^at/' file
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
at blah.blah.blah.blah(blah.java)
```

To prevent other section starting with `at` to be printed

```
awk '/SQLError.dispatchException/ {f=1} f && /^at/; !/^at/ {f=1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/SQLError.dispatchException/ {
:at
   N;s/\nat[^[:cntrl:]]*$/&/
   t at
   s/\n[^[:cntrl:]]*$//p;}' YourFile
```